# SSL handshake failure using javax.net.url in java

Tags: java, apache, ssl

I am able to hit the https(ONE-WAY) url using browser and page loaded successfully. But the same url is not working using java Url class. I am getting handshake failure. I enabled the javax.net.debug to all. All i could see in the log is "Client hello message" and then immediately the handshake failure message.

Apache is not showing any entry in error log and access log if i try using java url class. But the entry is shown if i hit the url in browser.

Any idea?

Comment: Could you tell us that the negotiated cipher scheme is? It might be that Java and your server have nothing in common...

Comment: In apache, i have below configuration 
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:!ADH:!MD5:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!3DES:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!AES128-SHA
In Java it uses TLSv1 only
*** ClientHello, TLSv1

Comment: main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 188
[Raw write]: length = 193
00C0: 74                                                 t
[Raw read]: length = 5
[Raw read]: length = 2
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Comment: Thanks [http://stackoverflow.com/users/2071828/boris-the-spider]. We added the supported cipher in apache and it started working..